# How to combine text items in a Siri Shortcut without skipping a joining character when a value is empty?

Tags: shortcut, siri

[image]

I am creating a tab-delimited file from reminders.  Not every item in every reminder has a value, so I expected that some rows would have 2 tab characters next to one another, but instead, I'm seeing that different rows end up with different numbers of values because the cases where I should be ending up with 2 adjacent tab characters are reduced to 1 tab character.

I suppose I could wrap each item in a conditional and insert "null" or something.  Is there a better way to do it to keep the shortcut as simple as possible?

Incidentally, I'm doing this as a Siri Shortcut as opposed to AppleScript (which I also wrote) because the Reminders AppleScript dictionary doesn't handle subtasks or sublists, takes minutes to run, and requires the Reminders app be open on the current desktop (if I want it to finish in a reasonable timespan) whereas the Siri shortcut runs in the background in a few seconds and *can* process sub-tasks/lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparently no way to tell `combine` to not skip tab characters when a value in the text items being combined is an empty string, so you *have* to set up conditionals to check for empty values, and supply a default string value (e.g. `null`) to keep the number of tab characters in the output consistent.  You could then remove those values later with a regex on the combined text output, if you really want concurrent tab characters.

### Alternative Suggestion

That said, I ultimately decided to output in json format (instead of tab-delimited) and used a `Dictionary` step to set all of the "column" values.  I added that dictionary to a list.  After the reminder loop, I created a new outer dictionary and set a key where the reminder list of dictionaries was the value.

Just note that if you have a list (e.g. of reminder titles), and that list happens to have 0 or 1 items, you end up with a similar problem.  Instead of missing tabs, your list in JSON is saved as a simple string, and you have to use a regular expression on the stringified JSON to fix the string value to make it a proper JSON list (so the json is consistent).

E.g. The JSON *should* be this:

```
{"listA": [], "listB": ["single value"], "listC": ["value1", "value2"]}
```

But unless you fix it, stringifying a dictionary with list values (e.g. listA (0 items), listB (1 item), and listC (2 items)) will produce:

```
{"listA": "", "listB": "single value", "listC": ["value1", "value2"]}
```

So you have to do 2 regex replace steps to:

- Replace `"listA":""` with `"listA":[]`
- Replace `"listB":"([^"]+)"` with `"listB":["$1"]`